# Entity framework with 2 joins on same table for column 1 or column 2

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to construct an EF query to either return column 1 or column 2.

Column 1 is pulled from a different table based on the relationships/join of the query.

Column 2 is pulled from the joined table.

This is for a survey/answer model. Some answers are hardcoded (e.g. user picks from a list) and some are free text.

Free text get saved in a table, and the user picked value is stored in a different table.

End goal is to have a POCO class with the question and answer:

```
public class SurveyResponse
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

My query looks like:

```
var surveyResponses = (from ias in dataContext.AnswerSet
                       join answer in dataContext.Answer on ias.AnswerSetID equals answer.AnswerSetID
                       join oa in dataContext.OptionalAnswer on answer.PossibleAnswerID equals oa.OptionalAnswerID // this line loses valuetext answer
                       where ias.LeadID.Equals(dbLead.leadID)
                       select new SurveyResponse() { Question = "question(todo)", Answer = (answer.ValueText != "" ? answer.ValueText : oa.Title)}).ToList();
```

And here is some of the data which shows why the join on optionalanswer loses the last row

```
PossibleAnswerID    ValueText
979D3ADF-4F9C-4F4D-AC9C-034CE960003A    
EF488701-683D-4855-A9A7-7F9D78468E63    
D442F616-6D4B-4176-9F08-133E2C655BE4    
5FD57A95-B385-4CAE-ADAB-1711CEA00A08    
NULL    Questions about sales
```

Comment: What is expected result and what result do you have?

Comment: Based on the data I showed you, the expected result is 5 items in surveyResponses, but I get 4 as the join to optionalanswer hides the null/question about sales @Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your query generates `inner join` in sql and thus it eliminates `Answer` with empty `PossibleAnswerID`. So you just need to change it to `left join`. It can be done like this

```
var surveyResponses = 
    (from ias in dataContext.AnswerSet
     join answer in dataContext.Answer on ias.AnswerSetID equals answer.AnswerSetID
     join oa in dataContext.OptionalAnswer on answer.PossibleAnswerID equals oa.OptionalAnswerID into optans // this line loses valuetext answer
     from oa in optans.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where ias.LeadID.Equals(dbLead.leadID)
     select new SurveyResponse() { Question = "question(todo)", Answer = (answer.ValueText != "" ? answer.ValueText : oa.Title)}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use fluent syntax, .Select can accept an `Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>>` argument.

Simplified:

```
Expression<Func<AnswerSetType, SomeClass>> func = SomeMethod();

dataContext.AnswerSet
    .Select(func)
    .ToList();
```

`SomeClass` could maybe simply be this depending on what exactly you need:

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    public string ValueFromColumn1OrColumn2 { get; set; }
}
```

`SomeMethod` is where you would define which value needs to be returned from your query:

```
public Expression<Func<AnswerSetType, SomeClass>> SomeMethod()
{
    if (condition)
    {
        return (answerSetType => new SomeClass { ValueFromColumn1OrColumn2 = answerSetType.Column1 });
    }
    else
    {
        return (answerSetType => new SomeClass { ValueFromColumn1OrColumn2 = answerSetType.Column2 });
    }
}
```

In the `Expression` you can also make use of navigation properties to access columns in a different table.

I am making the assumption here that both your columns have the same datatype.

Comment: In the Expression declaration, what is AnswerSetType ?

Comment: Your dataContext variable is, I'm assuming, a DbContext consisting of several DbSet<T> properties. One of which is AnswerSet. I was referring to the type you use for that DbSet.

Comment: Okay I am just not sure what condition would be.

Comment: You want your query to return either Column 1 or Column 2. What does "either" mean? That's your condition...